# windows.location does not work for me to redirecting to another html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i am trying to redirect from start.html to index.html since the input type submit is clicked. but it does not work with me.

this is how my start.html looks like:

> ````
>     <title>Login V16</title>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/css/main.css"> </head> <html> <body>
>     <div class="mail">
>         <h2>Input your Name and Submit</h2>
>         <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required()">
>             <ul>
>                 <li><input id="input100" type='text' name='text1' /></li>
>                 <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
>                 <li>
>                     <input type="submit" />
>             </ul>
>         </form>
>     </div>
>     <script>
>         function visit() {
>             var url = "js/Index.html";
>             window.location(url);
>         }
>         var input = document.getElementById("input100");
>         input100.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
>             if (event.keyCode === 13) {
>                 event.preventDefault();
>                 // document.getElementsByClassName("login-button").click();
>             }
>         });
>         function required() {
>             var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
>             if (empt == "") {
>                 alert("Please input a Value");
>                 return false;
>             } else {
>                 localStorage.setItem('username', document.getElementById('input100').value)
>                 visit()
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
>     </script> </body> </html> </html> ```
> ````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location is not a method, it's a property.  So instead of calling it like a function like you are doing (which is incorrect):

```
window.location(url);
```

You must simply set it's value, like so:

```
window.location = url;
```

Edit: You have more issues with your code. Change the onsubmit attribute on the form so it looks like this (add return before the name of the function):

```
onsubmit="return required()"
```

In the else statement in the required() method, also return false.  That will prevent the form from submitting which will take precedence over what visit() is trying to do.

Updated code which works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login V16</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/css/main.css"> </head> <html> <body>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mail">
        <h2>Input your Name and Submit</h2>
        <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="return required()">
            <ul>
                <li><input id="input100" type='text' name='text1' /></li>
                <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" />
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function visit() {
            var url = "js/Index.html";
            window.location = url;
        }
        var input = document.getElementById("input100");
        input100.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                // document.getElementsByClassName("login-button").click();
            }
        });
        function required() {
            var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
            if (empt == "") {
                alert("Please input a Value");
                return false;
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('username', document.getElementById('input100').value)
                visit()
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are more issues with your code, see my updated answer.

Comment: is there any trick how to redirect the user from index.html to start.html(start site for the user) since he tries to refresh index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
window.location.href= url
```